# Почему приложение не меняется после изменения кода

Tags: android-studio

В приложение есть кнопка перехода на новое окно (activity), я изменил обработчик нажатия, но после запуска всё равно остался переход на новое окно
обработка нажатия

```
private Button passTestButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {
    passTestButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.passTestButton);
    passTestButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    passTestButton.setText("q1");
                    /*Intent intent = new Intent(".PassTestActivity");
                    startActivity(intent);*/

                }
            }
    );
}
```

Comment: переформулируйте текст вопроса, лично мне не очень понятно что у вас происходит в приложении. Но может дело во мне :)

Comment: Нет, это я просто так составляю вопросы. Есть обработчик кнопки, изменяю его так, чтобы он НЕ переходил на новое окно (как раньше), а менял название, однако, при запуске (через Shift + F10) будто не было изменений в коде. То есть он выполняет закомментированную часть, а     passTestButton.setText("q1");   не видит

Comment: попробуйте перестроить проект, и запустить его нажав на зеленый треугольник, вообще студия с трудом выполняет заккоментированные участки кода

Comment: Если зелёный треугольник это "Run", то я через него и запускаю. Так же я использовал "Make project" (зелёный молоток) и опять запускал, результат один

Comment: а попробуйте удалить приложение с эмулятора, и вообще мне не очень понятно как вы кнопку обрабатываете, дополните код немного, если не сложно

Comment: Это весь код из `MainActivity`. Приложение с эмулятора удалял и заново запускал, но сейчас ещё раз проверил, чтобы убедиться, всё по прежнему

Comment: а почему вы не можете перекинуть слушатель и саму кнопку в onCreate()? в чем сакральный смысл использования функции?

Comment: перекинул [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/x9rXsgqL), ничего не изменилось

Comment: у вас там ошибка есть небольшая, сейчас переброшу ваш код в ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как у вас:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button passTestButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.passTestButton);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        passTestButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        passTestButton.setText("q1");
                        /*Intent intent = new Intent(".PassTestActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);*/

                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

вот как нужно:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button passTestButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        passTestButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.passTestButton);
        passTestButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        passTestButton.setText("q1");
                        /*Intent intent = new Intent(".PassTestActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);*/

                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

по логике должно работать нормально и правильно, проверьте должно все быть ок. Если будут вопросы - не стесняйтесь и пишите. Удачи :)

Comment: То ли я дурак, то ли у меня с средой что-то не ладное, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: очень странно получается, а попробуйте новый проект создать, может поможет

Comment: В новом проекте все работает, теперь мне стало ещё не понятнее почему в старом проекте не работало (похожая ситуация с эмулятором была у меня)

Comment: а попробуйте запустить новый проект, может там в кэше что-то сохранилось

Comment: В новом проекте все как раз отлично, спасибо за помощь